# Изменения на странице в реальном времени

Tags: php, long-poll

Пишу игровой портал. Пользователь подает заявку на игру, ждет соперника и играет.
Есть страница всех заявок. Задача обновлять данные в реальном времени.

То есть к примеру на странице 5 заявок, нужно показывать текущему пользователю на экран к примеру какой пользователь присоединился к заявке, дату создания заявки (минуту назад, 2 минуты назад и т.п.)

То есть сервер должен постоянно отвечать (что то типа новостей в вк, где они сами появляются).

Подскажите как это лучше всего реализовать? Копал в сторону long-poll или может простым SSE, нужно ли возвращать кусок html кода или по чуть чуть данные?

Comment: json посылайте лучше, а для SSE лучше использовать библиотечки которые умеют fallback в longpoll

Comment: использую eventsource

Comment: Можно для этого использовать setInterval, который будет с какой-то периодичностью вызывать функцию, которая в свою очередь будет отправлять запрос на сервер, в ответ принимать некие данные в формате JSON и при выполнении некоторых условий - изменять данные на странице.